# Google form quiz error in "ans feedback "

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have created an Appscript for a Google form "QUIZ". Keeping the default question point value as 1 point. Questions are required by default for all questions. Selects the questions and set the answer key. I am getting the below error and I am not able to set the feedback for the questions:

```
8:59:49 PM  Error   
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for FormApp.MultipleChoiceItem.setFeedbackForIncorrect.
createPMPQuiz   @ Quiz.gs:18
```

Below is the Google Appscript:

```
function createQuiz() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Quiz');

  // Enable Quiz settings
  form.setIsQuiz(true);

  // Add the first question
  var question1 = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  question1.setTitle('RGB stands for _______________.');
  question1.setChoices([
    question1.createChoice('Rod,Glue,Blue'),
    question1.createChoice('Red,Green,Blue', true),
    question1.createChoice('Reed,Green,Blur'),
    question1.createChoice('Rose,Girl,Bear')
  ]);
  question1.setRequired(true);
  question1.setPoints(1);
  question1.setFeedbackForIncorrect('Incorrect. Please try again.');
  question1.setFeedbackForCorrect('Correct! Red,Green,Blue.');

  // Publish the form
  var formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();
  Logger.log('Form URL: ' + formUrl);
}
```

Comment: Parameter for `setFeedbackForIncorrect` is of type `QuzFeedback` as shown here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/quiz-feedback.  See the example at the provided link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since it was taken from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

As [@Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) mentioned in the comments, the `setFeedbackForIncorrect` and `setFeedbackForCorrect` require a `QuizFeedback`, the documentation is a little outdated but I made a working version of your code based on it:

```
function createQuiz() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Quiz');

  // Enable Quiz settings
  form.setIsQuiz(true);

  // Add the first question
  var question1 = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  question1.setTitle('RGB stands for _______________.');
  question1.setChoices([
    question1.createChoice('Rod,Glue,Blue'),
    question1.createChoice('Red,Green,Blue', true),
    question1.createChoice('Reed,Green,Blur'),
    question1.createChoice('Rose,Girl,Bear')
  ]);
  question1.setRequired(true);
  question1.setPoints(1);
  question1.setFeedbackForIncorrect(
    FormApp.createFeedback().setText("Incorrect. Please try again.").build());
  question1.setFeedbackForCorrect(
    FormApp.createFeedback().setText("Correct! Red,Green,Blue.").build());

  // Publish the form
  var formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();
  Logger.log('Form URL: ' + formUrl);
}
```

---

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/quiz-feedback) uses `setDisplayText` while Apps Script would only accept `setText`, this has been already reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71636893).